# Why doesn't MS-SQL/PDO correctly infer parameter types for OFFSET clause?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

This code

```php
$stmt = db()->prepare('
    SELECT shoot, subject
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY shoot, subject
    OFFSET ? ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
');
$stmt->execute([100]);
$photos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

produces this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The number of
> rows provided for a OFFSET clause must be an integer.

If I explicitly cast to an integer, it works

```php
$stmt = db()->prepare('
    SELECT shoot, subject
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY shoot, subject
    OFFSET CAST(? AS INTEGER) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
');
$stmt->execute([100]);
$photos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As I understand it parameter types are "locked-in" when you call `prepare()` but (as the error indicates) an integer is the only thing that makes sense here. MS-SQL seems to be able to infer parameter types most of the time. I'm curious why it can't in this case.

Comment: Are you using emulated prepares?

Comment: What does XEvents say the parameter's type is being sent as?

Comment: @Dharman The docs make it sound like emulated prepares are only supported for OCI, Firebird, and MySQL. In any case `db()->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);` is false.

Comment: Does PDO not support proper, named parameters with strong, defined types? Throwing hands in the air and using `?` seems to invite exactly this problem (and as Dai implies, I suspect the issue is that PDO has inferred the wrong thing, not SQL Server).

Comment: In other words, you are having this issue because PDO is taking `[100]` and telling SQL Server “this is a string.” Not because SQL Server is guessing wrong. Will removing the square brackets help? Maybe, I don’t know. But really you should be explicitly declaring your parameter types instead of letting PDO (or SQL Server) guess.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker In this case, the user binds everything as a string. It's not PDO's fault. You can tell PDO to bind as an integer if you really want to.

Comment: Brackets are just PHP's syntax for defining an array (a list). To specify a type you have to use `bindValue()` instead

Comment: @Dharman My point is: you’re letting PDO tell SQL Server “this is a string.” [That won’t work.](https://dbfiddle.uk/fDgtRIHT) SQL Server hasn’t inferred the wrong thing, as the OP suggests, they let PDO force SQL Server to treat it as a string. Sure, there are cases where SQL Server might be nice and offer an implicit cast, but probably not in engine code added since 2005.

Comment: The answer is going to be to use `::bindParam` or similar, and explicitly specify int, rather than expect SQL Server to ignore PDO when it says “this is a string.”

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Which is precisely this question: why does SQL Server not offer an implicit cast. It's not about PDO because that's obvious that we bind everything as string. It works in most other contexts except OFFSET.

Comment: @Dharman did you read all of my words and follow the link? If you tell SQL Server _this is a string_, it’s going to believe you. Modern additions to the engine are going to be more adherent to those type definitions than loopholes that existed since earlier versions.

Comment: @Dharman “we bind everything as string” why? Just because you do that doesn’t mean SQL Server has to play along. Might be time to reconsider that approach, since there are methods to define the type without having to make anyone guess.

Comment: @Dharman it won’t work in other places either, e.g. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZVhPrgK). Basically, stop relying on implicit conversions from strings. That it works in some places doesn’t mean it works everywhere, and if you keep relying on it, you’re going to run into more places where magic doesn’t save you. If you know it’s an int, make it explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, SQL Server is doing implicit CASTs for you. PDO (at least with the Microsoft provided driver) sends `?` as a string unless you tell it otherwise. Usually as `nvarchar(4000)`, though interestingly it appears to depend on the first string you call it with.

XEvents reveals the parameter here is sent as `nvarchar(4000)`:

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("
    SELECT CASE WHEN ? = 100 THEN 'OneHundred' ELSE 'SomethingElse' END AS example
");
$stmt->execute([100]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

unsurprisingly, this one is also sent as `nvarchar(4000)`:

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("SELECT LEN(?) AS string_length_2");
$stmt->execute(['hi']);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

somewhat more surprisingly, this is sent as `nvarchar(max)`

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("SELECT LEN(?) AS string_length_5000");
$stmt->execute([str_repeat('a', 5000)]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

That of course begs the question, what if you send small data first, then large data later:

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("SELECT LEN(?) AS string_length");
$stmt->execute(['hi']);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);

$stmt->execute([str_repeat('a', 5000)]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

It turns out you get an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right
> truncation in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\photomgr\scratch.php:27

OK, so we've established that PDO is guessing parameter types, and it's bad at it. As pointed out by Rhythm Was a Lurker, the solution is to specify a type explicitly:

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("
    SELECT shoot, subject
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY shoot, subject
    OFFSET ? ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
");
$stmt->bindValue(1, 100, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```